# Strange Compile Errors in g++ (clang++ compiles fine)

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors, clang

I'm attempting to compile a file that instantiates this class.  GCC gives me cryptic errors, but clang compiles it without a complaint.

Errors:

```
statemachine.h: In member function ‘void state_machine<Data, T>::start_submachine(void (*)(state_machine<Data, T>&, T), void (*)(state_machine<Data, T>&, T))’:
statemachine.h:245: error: ‘substate_machine<Data, T>::substate_machine(state_machine<Data, T>*)’ is protected
statemachine.h:215: error: within this context
statemachine.h: In member function ‘state_machine<Data, T>* substate_machine<Data, T>::parent()’:
main.cpp:282:   instantiated from here
statemachine.h:138: error: ‘state_machine<Data, T>* state_machine<Data, T>::parent()’ is protected
statemachine.h:241: error: within this context
statemachine.h: In member function ‘void substate_machine<Data, T>::state_return()’:
main.cpp:282:   instantiated from here
statemachine.h:232: error: ‘void state_machine<Data, T>::return_from_sub()’ is protected
statemachine.h:254: error: within this context
```

Main.cpp is 282 lines long, the line that it's pointing to is just a closing brace }. Parent() is never called outside the class (so why would it complain about it being protected)?  And why would it complain about state_return() calling a protected method, as this *is* a member of the class.  Does GCC/G++ screw up with protected data members in templates?  I suspect (and this is just a hunch) it's trying to inline expand the functions like macros... but why?

The code:

```
#ifndef STATEMACHINE_H_INC
#define STATEMACHINE_H_INC

//#include <iostream> TODO:  Make better templated stream type
#include <memory>
#include <string>

const std::string null_string = "";

/* Class state_machine:
 *      Templated class to allow easy implementation of FSMs.
 * 
 *      HOW TO USE:
 *          - Make a type containing whatever data needs to be passed
 *            to the current state.
 *          - If necessary, create a preprocessor function run before
 *            the actual state is invoked (prefunc)
 *          - Create a function for each state.  In addition, each
 *            state can be made a submachine by using substate_machine
 *          - If necessary, specialize (INLINE and in the HEADER FILE)
 *            the finalize() method.
 *          - The function names should pretty much be self explanitory.
 *      
 *      Hooray for function pointers.  The code was 5x longer and 10x
 *      buggier before I implemented lexer as a state machine :D.
 * 
 *  NOTE:  This class COPY CONSTRUCTS from the hints provided (at least
 *         for now), so *don't* try and use your old pointer- it's not the
 *         same object!  This was done to simplify this class's
 *         implementation.  At some point I should probably change it...
 * 
 */

template <class Data, class T>
class state_machine {
public:
    //public use typedefs
    typedef void (*state)(state_machine<Data, T>&, T);
    typedef state prefunc_t;
    static void defprefunc(state_machine<Data, T>&, T);
    static void defstate(state_machine<Data, T>&, T);
    static void submachine_handle(state_machine<Data, T>&, T);
    //The above works with submachines because references are treated
    //by the standard like pointers- so polymorphism is allowed
private:
    prefunc_t prefunc;
    //don't feel like writing a full on destructor for one pointer
    std::auto_ptr<Data> internal_data;
    state curstate;
    state returnstate;
    //this MUST be an auto_ptr or our memory management gets REAL tricky
    std::auto_ptr < state_machine<Data, T> > substate;
protected:
    void init();
    void call(state_machine<Data, T>&, T);
    //this method allows submachine to get data from top of hierarchy.
    virtual state_machine<Data, T> * parent(); //return TOP of tree
    void return_from_sub(); //this is a slot, to use the qt term
public:
    //public interface
    state_machine(prefunc_t = defprefunc, Data * = NULL);
    Data& data();
    void change_state(state);
    //TODO:  change std::istream to a stream dependent on T
    //void add_stream(std::istream&);
    void add_char(T);
    //NULL here means curstate:
    void start_submachine(state, state = NULL);
    //this method is available for specialization
    void finalize();
    virtual void state_return();
};

/* class substate_machine:
 *      This class is a helper class to allow the creation of state
 *      machines as states within another state machine.  Submachines:
 *          -Share the same data.
 *          -Behave exactly like a regular state, except upon exiting
 *           the submachine the state should call the state_return()
 *           method, which allows control to flow to the parent machine.
 *          -Are invoked with the start_submachine() method.
 *      Basically, what allows them to share data is the protected
 *      virtual method parent(), which gets the state_machine object
 *      at the hierarchy's root.  This is never used by the submachine,
 *      only in the parent machine methods when accessing shared data
 *      (i.e. the subclass provides 'plug-in' functionality with this
 *      method), so it *could* be made a private virtual, but those seem
 *      to be 1. poorly understood and 2. overprotective in cases like
 *      this (i.e. do we *really* care if the submachine knows how to
 *      access its parent? no, in fact, we encourage it).
 * 
 *      The user should never see this class.  It is only to be used
 *      by the state_machine parent class provide transparent operation
 *      of substates (don't you love polymorphism>)
 */

template <class Data, class T>
class substate_machine : public state_machine<Data, T> {
    state_machine<Data, T> * parentsm; //direct parent state machine
    substate_machine() {} //Default construction causes failure
protected:
    virtual state_machine<Data, T> * parent();
    substate_machine(state_machine<Data, T>*);
public:
    virtual void state_return(); //send a signal to the parent machine
};

// definitions

//note that state_machine<Data, T>::parent() returns the TOP of the
//hierarchy, NOT the direct parent.

template <class Data, class T>
state_machine<Data, T> * state_machine<Data, T>::parent() {
    return this; //base class state machine must be at top of hierarchy
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::finalize() {
    //this is left to be <intentionally> specialized over
}

template <class Data, class T>
Data& state_machine<Data, T>::data() {
    //use parent here to allow all subs to access the hierarchy's shared
    //data as if they own it.
    return *(parent()->internal_data);
}

//these are two different functions for clarity's sake

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::defstate
(state_machine<Data, T>& self, T c) {
    //do nothing - default behavior
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::defprefunc
(state_machine<Data, T>& self, T c) {
    //do nothing - default behavior
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::
submachine_handle(state_machine<Data, T>& self, T c) {
    //handle a submachine
    self.substate->curstate(*(self.substate), c);
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::state_return() {
    //should NOT happen, but handle just in case.
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::init() {
    curstate = defstate;
    prefunc = defprefunc;
}

template <class Data, class T>
state_machine<Data, T>::state_machine
(prefunc_t func, Data * d) {
    init();
    //make a new data - copy construct if d is not null
    if (d) {
        internal_data = std::auto_ptr<Data>(new Data(*d));
    }
    else {
        internal_data = std::auto_ptr<Data>(new Data);
    }
    prefunc = func;
}

template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::change_state(state s) {
    curstate = s;
}

//the first state is the state to start a submachine in, the second
//state is the state to go into when the submachine returns to the
//parent, which is by default NULL (the current state)
template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::start_submachine(state s, state rs) {
    //get arround default argument errors (static resolution...)
    if (rs == NULL) {
        rs = curstate;
    }
    //set up submachines
    substate = std::auto_ptr<state_machine<Data, T> >(new substate_machine<Data, T>(this));
    substate->change_state(s);
    returnstate = rs;
    //set up the submachine state handler
    curstate = submachine_handle;
}

//preprocess and then process a character through the state machine.
template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::add_char(T c) {
    prefunc(*this, c);
    curstate(*this, c);
}

//this is a slot for the submachine to send its return signal to.
//basically just switches the function pointer back.
template <class Data, class T>
void state_machine<Data, T>::return_from_sub() {
    curstate = returnstate;
}

//now for the substate

template <class Data, class T>
state_machine<Data, T> * substate_machine<Data, T>::parent() {
    //remember, this is the top of the hierarchy.
    return parentsm->parent();
}

template <class Data, class T>
substate_machine<Data, T>::
substate_machine(state_machine<Data, T> * sm) {
    this->init();
    parentsm = sm;
    //initialization.  MUST BE INITIALIZED BY A PARENT THROUGH THIS CTOR
}

template <class Data, class T>
void substate_machine<Data, T>::state_return() {
    parentsm->return_from_sub();
    //sends the parent the return signal.
}

#endif
```

Thanks in advance for any input.  I would tag with clang++ but it won't let me...

Comment: That's way to much code for *me* at least to look into. Have you tried to remove code such that you still get at least one access error on GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things are protected alright, as the compiler says. A parent class cannot invoke the protected constructor of a derived class (it works the other way).

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(int) {}
public:
    void foo();
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    B(int):
        A(10) //OK here
     {}

};

void A::foo()
{
    B b(10); //error, that constructor is not accessible to A
}
```

And substate_machine's parent method is indeed trying to invoke a protected method through a pointer whose static type is not a substate_machine.

```
class A
{
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

class B: public A
{
    void bar() {
        this->foo(); //OK
        B other_b;
        other_b.foo(); //OK
        A a;
        a.foo(); //not OK
        A* b_ptr = &other_b;
        b_ptr->foo(); //not OK, static type of *b_ptr is not B
    }
};
```

I wonder if you expect `protected` to mean "any class can access any other class's protected parts as long as both classes belong to the same inheritance tree"?...

Comment: I knew about the super-call derived (I noticed that about 10 minutes after I posted).  However, I didn't know about the derived class not being able to call protected methods on the parent class's instances.  So now I have to ask: How should I change my code to conform?  The least-bad way I can think of is make the classes mutual friends, which seems to break encapsulation.  However, as all the polymorphism should be through the template (i.e. static, not dynamic), it shouldn't harm the use of the class, as state_machine and substate_machine *are* tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe g++ is correct. It looks like you're calling the protected initializing constructor of one template from the other template. It's in a different class and so isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in g++. It should not be checking the access of `substate_machine<Data, T>`'s constructor because it has a dependent type. The function containing the *new-expression* might only be instantiated for types where `substate_machine` is specialized and has a `public` constructor, so the compiler is not permitted to reject this code.

I cannot find a version of g++ that has this bug; which version are you using?